# jQuery datepicker appended not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have this problem when im trying to display a number of  fields, and onclick on those datepicker is supposed to run, if i put the  code outside the javascript it works just fine, so there must be something wrong with how i $.each loop it or with the append, but somehow im not getting it to work.

```
$(function() {

        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
        }); 

var val = [];

                $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){

                 val[i] = $(this).attr("id");

                });


                if(val == "")
                {

                alert('no selection');

                }
                else
                {

                    $.post("add_stuff", { "post" : val, "csrf" : cct },
                        function(data)
                        {
                            $("#content").empty();

                            json = eval('('+data+')');

                            $.each(json.datecheck, function() {
                                 $("#content").append("<h2>" + this.pName + " - " + this.pDesc + "</h2>");
                                 $("#content").append("<p>Datum: <input type='text' class='datepicker'></p>");
                            });


                        });


                }
            });
```

The post -> runs insert query in controller, and returns some json data thats looped out.
And for each row that's returned i want a inputfield , a working one :)
Would really appreciate some help, been struggling with this way too long now :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use .on() function for jquery 1.9+

```
$(document).on('click', '.datepicker', function(){
   $(this).timePicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
   }).focus();
   $(this).removeClass('datepicker'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The current binding will not work as the element does not exist.
As the addition of the the input field is dynamic, you would need to use [JQuery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Example -

```
$('.datepicker').live('click', function(){
    $(this).timePicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    }).focus();
    $(this).removeClass('datepicker');
});
```

Comment: Thought it was something like that, thanks alot that worked perfectly :)

Comment: how to use this when we put `from to date` `datepicker` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, `live` was removed in 1.9, could you revise to fit a modern solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".addSpan").click(function() {
        var i = $("#dateTab input") .length + 1;
        $("#dateTab").append($("<label>Date</label><input class='getDate id_"+ i +"' type='text' name='name[]' />"));
    });

    $( ".getDate" ).datepicker();
});
```